# RxApp CoreDispatcherScheduler is null

Tags: c#, uwp, reactiveui

I recently upgraded my project to RxUI 7.0 (from 6.5). When starting up my UWP app, it immediately crashes with the following exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ReactiveUI.RxApp' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: dispatcher
```

Here's one of the stacktraces:

```
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.CoreDispatcherScheduler..ctor(CoreDispatcher dispatcher)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.CoreDispatcherScheduler.get_Current()
   at ReactiveUI.PlatformRegistrations.<>c.<Register>b__0_5()
   at ReactiveUI.WaitForDispatcherScheduler.attemptToCreateScheduler()
   at ReactiveUI.PlatformRegistrations.Register(Action`2 registerFunction)
   at ReactiveUI.DependencyResolverMixins.InitializeReactiveUI(IMutableDependencyResolver resolver)
   at ReactiveUI.RxApp.<>c.<.cctor>b__0_0()
   at Splat.Locator.RegisterResolverCallbackChanged(Action callback)
   at ReactiveUI.RxApp..cctor()
```

Here's another

```
   at ReactiveUI.RxApp.get_MainThreadScheduler()
   at ReactiveUI.ReactiveList`1.setupRx(IEnumerable`1 initialContents, Double resetChangeThreshold, IScheduler scheduler)
   at ReactiveUI.ReactiveList`1..ctor()
   at NewBooru.ViewModels.HamburgerViewModel..ctor()
   at NewBooru.Views.MainPage..ctor()
   at NewBooru.NewBooru_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_31_MainPage()
   at NewBooru.NewBooru_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
```

The code where it crashes:

```
 public HamburgerViewModel()
        {
            MenuItems = new ReactiveList<MenuItem>
            {
                new MenuItem("link", "name", enum)
            };
        }
```

I can't imagine this slipping by unit tests or any manual testing. Do I need to do some extra initialization in the new version?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the issue is that the app's core Dispatcher doesn't get initialized until the App's OnLaunched. ReactiveUI expects that Dispatcher to be alive, and fails if it isn't. [Here's a link](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/1221) to the issue tracking this in the ReactiveUI repo.

The solution is to wait to call anything from ReactiveUI until after the app has fired OnLaunched.